# How to update data on entering state in AngularJS UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router for AngularJS and here is the question - at the moment when I'm clicking a link which sends me to specific state (using ui-sref) I want to send AJAX request to back end, get data, and render them in the template related to this new state. To which event should I listen for making AJAX request? Could you please give me a code example for this listener? I understand that the question seems to be simple, but I'm new in AngularJS world.

Thank you.

Comment: Suggest you go through some tutorials as well as the code in the ui-router demos

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `resolve` property on your state configuration. See **[ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)**

Then inject the resolved property as a dependency of the controller.

**Example:**

```
$stateProvider.state('about', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController',
    resolve: {
        something: function ($http) {
            // make ajax request
            return $http.get(...).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

In the controller, we inject the data that will be resolved, i.e. `something` :

```
app.controller('AboutController', function (..., something, ...) {
    // The data resolved by ui-router is ready when the controller is instantiated
}
```